# Getting an error while using the BaseLLMOutputParser method in LangChain.js?

Tags: langchain

I am getting an error while using the BaseLLMOutputParser method. Here is the usage and error message.

```js
const outputParser = new BaseLLMOutputParser(schema());
const memory = new BufferWindowMemory({
  k: 3
});
const chain = new ConversationChain({
  llm: model,
  memory: memory,
  outputParser: outputParser,
});

const output = await chain.call({
  input: "text",
});
console.log("output", output);
```

`"errorMessage": "this.parseResult is not a function"`